# generated $\sigma$-algebra by outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have the following questions:

$\mu$ should be a pre measure on the semiring $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mu^*$ the outer measure generated by $\mu$. Define
$$\mathcal{M}(\mu^*)=\{A \subseteq X: \mu^*(Q)=\mu^*(Q \cap A)+\mu^*(Q \cap A^C) \text{ for } Q \in \sigma(\mathcal{H})\}.$$
a) Show that $\mathcal{M}(\mu^*)=\mathcal{A}(\mu^*)$, where $\mathcal{A}(\mu^*)= \{A \subseteq X: \mu^*(Q)=\mu^*(Q \cap A)+\mu^*(Q \cap A^C) \forall Q \subseteq X\} $.

b) Conclude that $\mathcal{A}(\mu^*)$ is the largest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{H}$ on which $\mu^*$ is a measure.

Here is how I've come:

a) "$\mathcal{M}(\mu^*) \supseteq \mathcal{A}(\mu^*)$" holds, since the measurability is fulfilled for every $Q \subseteq X$, thus it also holds for every $Q \in \sigma(\mathcal{H})$.

"$\mathcal{M}(\mu^*) \subseteq \mathcal{A}(\mu^*)$": Let $B \subseteq X$ be arbitrary. Then we can find a set $M \in \sigma(\mathcal{H})$ s.t. $B\subseteq M$ and $\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(M)$. (This we proved in our lecture). By definition of $\mathcal{M}(\mu^*)$, we have for every $A \in \mathcal{M}(\mu^*): \mu^*(M)=\mu^*(M \cap A)+\mu^*(M \cap A^C)$. Now $\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(M)$ and we also have to have $\mu^*(B \cap A) = \mu^*(M \cap A)$ and $\mu^*(B \cap A^C) = \mu^*(M \cap A^C)$, since otherwise $\mu^*(A \cap (M\backslash B))>0$ and $\mu^*(A^C \cap (M\backslash B))>0$. Thus the measurability condition holds for every $B \subseteq X$, and thus $A \in \mathcal{A}(\mu^*)$.

b) Since every $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A} \supseteq \mathcal{H}$ on which $\mu^*$ is a measure has to satisfy the measurability condition, it follows that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{M}(\mu^*)$.

Is this true or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any mistakes (uptil now).

Your reasoning under b) is a bit vague to me. Maybe you mean exactly the same, but I would formulate it like this:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra with $\mathcal{H}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$
and such that $\mu^{*}$ restricted to $\mathcal{A}$ is a measure.

Then   $\mu^{*}\left(Q\right)=\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A\right)+\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A^{c}\right)$ is true for every $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and every $Q\in\sigma\left(\mathcal{H}\right)\subseteq\mathcal{A}$.

This tells us exactly that $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{M}\left(\mu^{*}\right)=\mathcal{A}\left(\mu^{*}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I meant the same but wasn't precise enough!